# jupyter toc2 floating window cannot be moved or folded

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

After a recent package update on Python 3.9 the toc2 extension in jupyter notebook stopped working reliably. When a notebook is opened, the TOC floating window appears, however, the TOC window:

1. Can only be moved (dragged) once after the notebook is loaded: after the initial move, the window cannot be moved anymore
2. Cannot be resized by dragging the corner (but can via editing the cell metadata and reloading the notebook)
3. Cannot be folded (or, if configured to start as folded, cannot be unfolded (expanded))

The sections in the TOC2 can be folded/unfolded as usual, and can be used to navigate the notebook.

Please let me know what additional info I should provide for troubleshooting.

Thank you,
Alex

UPDATE: Tried to use toc2 in a fresh install of Py 3.11.1, packages and no user .jupyter and .ipython directories (removed them and they were recreated). Outcome is exactly the same: TOC window has the same exact problems.

Commands used:

```
pip install notebook
pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am not sure what causes the problem, but I found out that downgrading the *notebook* package version to before 6.5.1 eliminates the problem:

```
pip install notebook==6.4.12
```

In *notebook* v6.4.12 the problem does not exist. Note that the notebook extension packages are still at their latest (most up-to-date) versions, apparently they do not need to be downgraded: *jupyter-contrib-nbextensions* is v0.7.0, and *jupyter-nbextensions-configurator* is v0.6.1.